# Spread function on data frame with duplicates in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to split my replicate from my results in my dataset in an efficient way. I used this data as an example:

```
x <- data.frame(sample = c("AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "CC"),
                Gene = c("HSA-let1","HSA-let1","HSA-let1","HSA-let1","HSA-let1","HSA-let1"),
                Cq = c(14.55, 14.45, 13.55, 13.45, 16.55, 16.45))
```

The problem is that the two duplicates have the same name in "Sample" and "Gene". so when I tried:

```
spread(x,Gene,Cq)
```

I get duplicate identifiers error.I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209388/r-spread-function-on-data-frame-with-duplicates) fix code below and it gives two values in one coloumn separated by ",". This was almost successful, but I want them separated:

```
x_test <- dcast(setDT(x), Gene ~ sample, value.var = 'Cq',
                fun.aggregate = function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```

I did also tried this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592094/r-spreading-multiple-columns-with-tidyr?noredirect=1&lq=1) tidyr solution, but I dont understand enough R to make it work.

```
x_test2 <- x %>% 
      gather(variable, value, -(Gene:Cq)) %>%
      unite(temp, Cq, variable) %>%
      spread(temp, value)
```

I want my dataset to look like this:

```
# Gene    AA_1   AA_2 BB_1   BB_2  CC_1  CC_2
# HSA-let 14.55 14.45 13.55 13.45 16.55 16.45
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the samples unique, then spread:

```
x %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(sample = paste(sample, rn, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(-rn) %>% 
  spread(key = sample, value = Cq)

# # A tibble: 1 x 7
#     Gene      AA_1  AA_2  BB_1  BB_2  CC_1  CC_2
#     <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#   1 HSA-let1  14.6  14.4  13.6  13.4  16.6  16.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `sample` column:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)[, sample := paste(sample, ifelse(!duplicated(sample), '1', '2'), sep = '_')]
dcast(x, ...~sample, value.var = 'Cq')
#        Gene  AA_1  AA_2  BB_1  BB_2  CC_1  CC_2
# 1: HSA-let1 14.55 14.45 13.55 13.45 16.55 16.45
```

Note: `spread` should be called as `spread(x, sample, Cq)`.

### Edit

If you have diferent number of repeated values (not always 2), you can do:

```
x <- setDT(x)[order(sample),]
x[, sample := paste(sample, unlist(lapply(table(x$sample), function(x) 1:x)), sep = '_')]
dcast(x, ...~sample, value.var = 'Cq')
```

Beware that `x` should be sorted by `sample`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% group_by(Gene) %>%
  mutate(sample = paste(sample, seq(n()), sep = "_")) %>%
  spread(sample, Cq)
```